# If else statement in Tornado/python

Tags: python, if-statement, tornado

I have this python code in Tornado:

```
if not usr:
    self.lock_tables("write", ['devices_permissions'])
        self.db.execute("INSERT devices_permissions SET user_id=%s, network_id=%s, device_id=%s, perm=%s",
                         usrid, netid, sensid, perm)
        self.unlock_tables();

    else:

      if perm == 0:
        self.lock_tables("write", ['devices_permissions'])
        self.db.execute("DELETE FROM devices_permissions \
                         WHERE user_id=%s AND device_id=%s", usrid, sensid)
        self.unlock_tables();


      else:
        self.lock_tables("write", ['devices_permissions'])
        self.db.execute("UPDATE devices_permissions SET perm=%s \
                         WHERE user_id=%s AND device_id=%s", perm, usrid, sensid)
        self.unlock_tables();
```

I have a problem with the second *if...else* statement. My program enter in the first else block, but in the second *if...else* seems not to work the *if perm == 0* statement. I have print the *perm* variable and its value is 0. So I don't know where sould be the error.

I want this *if...else* statement because I want delete from my DB the users that didn't have anymore a permission on a device.

*perm* is a variable of value 0 or 1. *usr* is a list of user. Thank you very much.

**EDIT**

I change the statement in this way:

```
# Check whether the user has already priviledges on the device
    self.lock_tables("read", ['devices_permissions'])
    usr = self.db.get("SELECT device_id, user_id FROM devices_permissions \
                              WHERE user_id=%s AND device_id=%s", usrid, sensid)
    self.unlock_tables();

    if not usr:
    self.lock_tables("write", ['devices_permissions'])
        self.db.execute("INSERT devices_permissions SET user_id=%s, network_id=%s, device_id=%s, perm=%s",
                         usrid, netid, sensid, perm)
        self.unlock_tables();

    elif perm == 0:
        self.lock_tables("write", ['devices_permissions'])
        self.db.execute("DELETE FROM devices_permissions \
                         WHERE user_id=%s AND device_id=%s", usrid, sensid)
        self.unlock_tables();          

    else:
        self.lock_tables("write", ['devices_permissions'])
        self.db.execute("UPDATE devices_permissions SET perm=%s \
                         WHERE user_id=%s AND device_id=%s", perm, usrid, sensid)
        self.unlock_tables();
```

and after some test I think that the program enter always in the if not usr statement, also if the usr list is not empty. What's the problem?

Comment: Re-check your indentation. Also you don't generally use `;` after lines in Python -- is there a specific reason for this?

Comment: No I don't know. But if I have a usr list, and the program works, it's because the statement works. In any words, also when perm=0, the query executed is the second, the UPDATE query. In the DB I have the same row with perm=0, but I want delete it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could it be that `perm` is the *string* zero rather than an integer zero? If so, the test `perm == 0` would fail. You can answer this question with a print statement:

```
print type(perm)
```

if it prints `<type 'str'>` then that's your problem.

Comment: yeah! I edit the condition with `if perm == '0'`. Thank you!!!